# pyimage2 does not exist error when I try to insert an image to window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to insert an image to window but I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Afro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Afro\Desktop\h.py", line 151, in start
pic_lab = Label(wind,image=pik)
File "C:\Users\Afro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2605, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
File "C:\Users\Afro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2138, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

Here's my code

```
wind = Tk()
name = money.jpg'
pik = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(name))
pic_lab = Label(wind,image=pik)
pic_lab.grid()
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

The string 'money.jpg' that is assigned to the variable name is missing a single quotation mark on the left.